# UISplitViewController - How can I present another table view controller temporarily in place of the small master view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

`UISplitViewController` - How can I present another `TableViewController` temporarily in place of the small master `ViewController`?

Normally the smaller master `ViewController` on the left is embedded in a navigation controller, I want to push another `ViewController` on top of it to select something and the get back to the initial one.

Looking through Apple's documentation but it hasn't clicked for me.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uisplitviewcontroller_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISplitViewController/showViewController:sender:

There is method, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
- (void)showViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
                    sender:(id)sender
```

Comment: Check my blogpost, it should help you - http://swiftwala.com/multiple-detail-views/ You should use segues done in Storyboard or call segues using performSegues method.

Comment: Thanks but it never got this to actually work. It would be great if you could find the time to answer my question. I would upvote it and mark it as the answer... you get points :D

Comment: I know I get points, if you vote. However I am not sure if reminding about that is the best way to ask for an answer. You should have instead written about what you didn't understand from my post or code. Anyways I have tried to answer you and hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call showViewController. You need to actually include a TableView Controller and then create a segue from Master View to 2nd Table View (You do this by control-dragging from 1st VC to 2nd VC)

If your Master View Controller also contains a TableView and if you use Static Cells, then you can control+drag from cell to 2nd TableView and your job is done. 2nd TableView will open automatically when someone selects a cell on 1st TableView.

If you use Prototype cells in MasterView, then you need to call `performSegueWithIdentifier` method inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and it will open second TableView.

All this is explained in detail in my [post](http://swiftwala.com/multiple-detail-views) and [link](https://github.com/palewar/Swift-Samples) for the working code is also included. If you carefully read the post and go through the code, I am sure you will understand everything.

If you have specific questions even after reading the post, I would be happy to answer.